# Tracking solr log request and response in datastax solr

Tags: logging, solr, datastax, datastax-enterprise

We are using datastax solr , how we can get logs for solr search queries . Can I know the location of the file and have to make any changes in logback.xml to show log access and response log ?

If I search for any query in solr , it should be logged and reponse data location in logfile .

Comment: I believe this goes to your DSE system.log (/var/log/cassandra/system.log in a package install). You can also view the logging tab in the  solr admin screen.

Answer (score 0):

@phact is correct.  The DSE Search logs for Solr are at /var/log/cassandra/system.log.  Also you can make changes to the logging level in the logback.xml.  Here's the docs page [docs page](http://docs.datastax.com/en/datastax_enterprise/4.7/datastax_enterprise/srch/srchLog.html) explaining the levels.